# Cannot get current processing time for I-485 when family based file

Tags: immigration, greencard

I am trying to figure out what would be the processing time for my parents when I file for their adjustment of status. I was trying to find that out by searching I-485 processing time. I checked online and there is a uscis portal to help find the processing times for I-485 which is located here at https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/

However, it only shows processing times for employment-based cases Not family-based. How can I figure out how to find processing times for family-based file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it only shows processing times for employment-based cases Not
>   family-based. How can I figure out how to find processing times for
>   family-based file?

After you select form I-485, you have to select a service center or local field office in the drop-down menu. You probably selected a service center, which does not process family-based I-485s. If you select a local field office, it will contain processing times for family-based I-485s for that field office.